# Use sklearn `KBinsDiscretizer` within a pipeline on specific columns and return a data frame

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I need to apply a `KBinsDiscretizer` as a step within a `sklearn.pipeline` only on specific columns and return it as a pandas dataframe as following:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import KBinsDiscretizer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline


class PandasColumnTransformer(ColumnTransformer):
    def transform(self, X: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
        return pd.DataFrame(super().transform(X), columns=X.columns, index=X.index)

    def fit_transform(self, X: pd.DataFrame, y=None) -> pd.DataFrame:
        return pd.DataFrame(super().fit_transform(X), columns=X.columns, index=X.index)


class PandasKBinsDiscretizer(KBinsDiscretizer):

    def __init__(self, n_bins):
        super(PandasKBinsDiscretizer, self).__init__(n_bins, encode='ordinal')

    def transform(self, X):
        self.col_names = list(X.columns.values)
        X = super(PandasKBinsDiscretizer, self).transform(X)
        X = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=self.col_names)
        return X


binner_on_numeric = PandasColumnTransformer(transformers=[
                ("binner",  PandasKBinsDiscretizer(2), 'numeric_col_to_change')])


pp = Pipeline([('binner_just_numeric', binner_on_numeric)])

d = {'numeric_col_not_to_change': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
     'numeric_col_to_change': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

res = pp.fit_transform(df)

assert isinstance(res, pd.DataFrame)
```

Im getting the following error:

```
ValueError: 1D data passed to a transformer that expects 2D data. Try to specify the column selection as a list of one item instead of a scalar.
```

Any help on that would we awsome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs because you are selecting one element in your `ColumnTransformer`. You can change it to a 2D array by using a list `['numeric_col_to_change']`.

You can also specify how you want to treat elements that are not handle by the `ColumnTransformer` with the `remainder` parameter. `remainder='passthrough'` will simply return them as-is instead of removing them.

This should work:

```
binner_on_numeric = PandasColumnTransformer(transformers=[
                ("binner",  PandasKBinsDiscretizer(2), ['numeric_col_to_change'])]
                ,remainder='passthrough')
```

`res = pp.fit_transform(df)` will return the following dataframe:

```
   numeric_col_not_to_change  numeric_col_to_change
0                        0.0                    1.0
1                        0.0                    2.0
2                        0.0                    1.0
3                        1.0                    2.0
4                        1.0                    1.0
5                        1.0                    2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Antoine, Yehoshaphat,

I was just trying to solve this same problem and I saw your question and answer. I wonder if this code also solves your problem (without classes) =)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import KBinsDiscretizer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

X = np.array([[-2, 1, -4,   -1],
              [-1, 2, -3, -0.5],
              [ 0, 3, -2,  0.5],
              [ 1, 4, -1,    2]])
df_X = pd.DataFrame(X)
df_X.columns = ['f0', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3']
num_cols = ['f0', 'f1']
binner_on_numeric2 = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
                ("binner", KBinsDiscretizer(n_bins=3, strategy='uniform', encode='ordinal'), num_cols)],
                remainder='passthrough')

pp = Pipeline([('binner_just_numeric2', binner_on_numeric2)])
res = pp.fit_transform(df_X)
#assert isinstance(res, pd.DataFrame)
res
```

Thank you very much.

Kind regards =),

David